# Error While embeding Orbeon Form In Next.Js app using JavaScript Embedding API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, orbeon

I have a Orbeon form which I want to embed in my Next.Js app. From the Orbeon documents I found the below document :

https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/javascript-api

As per the document I am trying to use like below code snippet in my Next.js application :

```
ORBEON.fr.API.embedForm(
    document.getElementById("my-container-element"),
    "/orbeon",
    "human-resources",
    "job-application",
    "new"
)
.then(() => {
    console.log("`embedForm()` successfully loaded the form");
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.log("`embedForm()` returned an error");
  console.log(e);
});
```

I am getting the error "ORBEON is undefined".
Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the JavaScript Embedding API in your page, as described in the "JavaScript to include" section of the [JavaScript Embedding API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/javascript-api)?

If you have, the problem may be caused by your code running before this script. In this case, you may want to change the order of the `<script>` so that the JavaScript Embedding API script element appears before your own script or the Next.js script.

Comment: Yes , I have added the <script> as mentioned in the document . But as its a Next.Js app , its throwing the compilation error.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Next.Js, but maybe this article on [how to import third-party libraries in Next.Js](https://frontend-digest.com/how-to-import-third-party-scripts-into-nextjs-d2f353a6226f) could help? If not, you can ask the Next.js community here on Stack Overflow.